# I want to fetch the last altered records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a main table . I will get some real time records added to that table .I want to fetch all records which has been added ,altered or changed in  previous existing records.

How can i Achieve this ?

Comment: You can add trigger on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 commonly used approaches:

- Track changes with another table through a trigger.

Should be something similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Tracking (
    ID INT,
    -- Your original table columns
    TrackDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    TrackOperation VARCHAR(100))

GO

CREATE TRIGGER TrackingTrigger ON OriginalTable AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Tracking(
        ID,
        TrackOperation
        -- Other columns
        )
    SELECT
        ID = ISNULL(I.ID, D.ID),
        TrackOperation = CASE
            WHEN I.ID IS NOT NULL AND D.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Update'
            WHEN I.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Insert'
            ELSE 'Delete' END
        -- Other columns
    FROM
        inserted AS I
        FULL JOIN deleted AS D ON I.ID = D.ID -- ID is primary key

END

GO
```

- Include `CreatedDate`, `ModifiedDate` and `IsDeleted` columns on your table. `CreatedDate` should have a default with current date, `ModifiedDate` should be updated each time your data is updated and `IsDeleted` should be flagged when you are deleting (and not actually being deleted). This option requires a lot more handling that the previous one, and you won't be able to track consecutive updates.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to search your table first from the sys.objects and grab that object id before using the usage_stats table.

```
 declare @objectid int
 select @objectid = object_id from sys.objects where name = 'YOURTABLENAME'

 select top 1 * from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats where object_id = @objectid
 and last_user_update is not null
 order by last_user_update
```

> If you have Identity column in your table you may find last inserted row information through SQL query. And for that, we have multiple options like:

```
@@IDENTITY
SCOPE_IDENTITY
IDENT_CURRENT
```

> All three functions return last-generated identity values. However, the scope and session on which last is defined in each of these functions differ.